# iteration using map for parameter values

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

Say I have a simple power analysis:

```
> power.t.test(power = .90, delta = 1)
```

I would like to have this function for all permutations of values from two vectors with power and delta values:

```
> power_vector <- c(0.85, 0.90, 0.95)
> delta_vector <- c(0.5, 1, 1.5)
```

so that the first function would use a power of 0.85 and a delta of 0.5, the second a power of 0.85 and delta of 1, ... until all permutations are exhausted.

Can this be accomplished with `purrr:map()` or `purrr:map2()`?

Comment: `map2(power_vector, delta_vector, ~power.t.test(power = .x, delta = .y))`, or in base R, `Map(power.t.test, power = power_vector, delta = delta_vector)`

Comment: @alistaire, it looks like maybe he wants `power.tests = expand.grid(power_vector, delta_vector) %>% 
  pmap(~power.t.test(power=..1, delta=..2))` in order to get all combinations.

Comment: @eipi10 Oops, failed at reading again. `cross2(power_vector, delta_vector) %>% map(~power.t.test(power = .x[[1]], delta = .x[[2]]))` to add a Cartesian join, or in base maybe `do.call(Map, c(power.t.test, expand.grid(delta = delta_vector, power = power_vector)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::cross2` to do a cross (Cartesian) join to get the combinations in a single list, then iterate with `map`:

```r
library(purrr)

power_vector <- c(0.85, 0.90, 0.95)
delta_vector <- c(0.5, 1, 1.5)

tests1 <- cross2(power_vector, delta_vector) %>% 
    map(~power.t.test(power = .x[[1]], delta = .x[[2]]))

tests1[[1]]
#> 
#>      Two-sample t test power calculation 
#> 
#>               n = 72.80053
#>           delta = 0.5
#>              sd = 1
#>       sig.level = 0.05
#>           power = 0.85
#>     alternative = two.sided
#> 
#> NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Another approach is to make a named list of the vectors, call `cross` on it, and then iterate `lift(power.t.test)` over the results, where `lift` modifies the function to take a list of parameters as an input (a backwards `do.call` or `purrr::invoke`, if you will):

```r
tests3 <- list(power = power_vector, 
               delta = delta_vector) %>% 
    cross() %>% 
    map(lift(power.t.test))

tests3[[3]]
#> 
#>      Two-sample t test power calculation 
#> 
#>               n = 104.928
#>           delta = 0.5
#>              sd = 1
#>       sig.level = 0.05
#>           power = 0.95
#>     alternative = two.sided
#> 
#> NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

In base R,

```r
tests2 <- do.call(Map, 
                  c(power.t.test, 
                    expand.grid(power = power_vector, 
                                delta = delta_vector)))

tests2[[2]]
#> 
#>      Two-sample t test power calculation 
#> 
#>               n = 85.03129
#>           delta = 0.5
#>              sd = 1
#>       sig.level = 0.05
#>           power = 0.9
#>     alternative = two.sided
#> 
#> NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Answer (score 1):

Use expand.grid for the combinations and pass to `pmap`, since `map` throws an error:

```
df_map <- expand.grid(power=power_vector, delta=delta_vector)
purrr::pmap(df_map, power.t.test)
```

Since that produces a list and you might just have expected a vector:

```
sapply( purrr::pmap(df_map, power.t.test), "[[", "n")
[1]  72.800532  85.031289 104.927952  18.968545  22.021098  26.989219   9.053694  10.401465
[9]  12.598722

> cbind( df_map, n=sapply( purrr::pmap(df_map, power.t.test), "[[", "n") )
  power delta          n
1  0.85   0.5  72.800532
2  0.90   0.5  85.031289
3  0.95   0.5 104.927952
4  0.85   1.0  18.968545
5  0.90   1.0  22.021098
6  0.95   1.0  26.989219
7  0.85   1.5   9.053694
8  0.90   1.5  10.401465
9  0.95   1.5  12.598722
```